# why mobile menu toggle button is not working?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My website’s menu is working on desktops and large screens. when I resize my browser to a small size or open my site on mobile then menu toggle button does not work and the menu dropdown does not show up.
My website running the latest Version: 3.2.4.

I also tried deactivating the plugins and clearing the cache but nothing works.

Before the update, I was facing the same issue but when updated to the latest issue goes away. now it’s back again.
To review the issue please check on the [website](https://printebill.com).
Please help me.

Comment: You have JS error in console, try to fix those first check your menu toggle works or not.

Comment: I resolved those but still, the toggle button issue is there.